# Web application with specific architecture

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, web-applications, architecture

In this question i want to know the best way which helps me build web application with next requirements:

1. We have one DB with confedential information(for example it has table "Customers"). It should locate on customer's territory.
2. We have web application(It is remote for customer).
   In this application concrete info(for example, customer's name) shouldn't left customer's territory(hardware, software).
   My first solution: create local web application. When my remote app get query's result from local db, it will be only objects' id. Then my remote app will redirect this to the local app, and local app will send query with IDs as parameters to local DB. And then local app will get necessary information. I don't know whethe it is possible, but I suppose that's very bad architecture.
   And second variant - information encoding.
   Maybe there are another ways. I will be happy to hear your advices. Thank you.

Comment: If the remote app is going to redirect the client to the local app, what is then the purpose of the remote app? Why not move all functionality to the local app?

Comment: I ask it myself, but we want to create web-service. In perspective, it should work for many customers.